# H1 tag solutions for the main page

Tags: best-practices, homepage, h1

I know that the question has beed asked a lot but I'm asking for your advice and "best practices" on the real example. I know what H1 tag is but I'm always in trouble when it comes to the main / home page of a website. Here I made a quick example of simple home page:

[image]

Logo (as an image, cause the font used is commercial) and a menu in the header. Then we have some (many in real world) blocks, each of them has it's own "meaning" like news, customers' logos, subscribe block, search, etc., each of the blocks has it's own H2 header. But the company itself doesn't write anything about themselves on the home page and I can't really say that one block is more important than the others. So my question is - what is the best option for H1 tag in these cases?

Comment: You can easily rank a business without the business name in a h1. Logo ALT and footer copyright is more than enough for Google to establish the business name, even more so if its added to Google My Business. The H1 should be applied to the most important element of the page, in this case API DATA because its at the top.

Comment: The h1 tag should be what the page is about, however, for the home page, the h1 tag could represent what the site is about. As Simon says, it should be the top most item. Do not resort to tricks. Keep it simple. Cheers!!

Comment: These days tags don't even matter.   Google sees any large bold text above the fold as important.   It doesn't matter if it is in an `H1` or a `span` styled that way with CSS.   Since Google has been rendering pages, its algorithms for identifying the important text on the page have become much more sophisticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont worry about forcing the H1 to be the company name. Google will do just fine deducting this from the content, domain name, and page title. H1 should define content. Additionally make sure to only use H1 once and not to use it to wrap an image.